# Why do we have Function.call in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
> Function.call == Function.prototype.call
true
> Function.prototype == Function
false
```

Why do `Function.prototype.*` methods exist as `Function.*`? It seems inconsistent.

This isn't the case with any other primary type (`Array.slice` doesn't exist but `Array.prototype.slice` does).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `Function` itself is the prototype of `Function`

```
console.log(Function instanceof Function);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Function.prototype);
```

So, all the functions in the `Function`s prototype are available in `Function` also.

Quoting [the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4),

> The Function prototype object is itself a Function object (its [[Class]] is "Function")

---

Another way to confirm this would be,

```
console.log(Function.call === Function.prototype.call);
```

it means that the `Function.call` object and `Function.prototype.call` object are the same.

```
console.log(Function.hasOwnProperty('call'));
```

it means that the `Function` object itself doesn't have `call` property.

```
console.log(Function.prototype.hasOwnProperty('call'));
```

it means that `Function.prototype` object has the `call` property.

---

> `Array.slice` doesn't exist but `Array.prototype.slice` do

Because `Array` function's prototype is `Function` object, not the `Array` object.

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Array) === Function.prototype);
```

That is why we get `call`, `apply`, `bind` etc on the `Array` function. It `Array` object had been the prototype of `Array`, then `slice` would have been available on the `Array` object also.

Comment: yep. Function is a constructor. `Array.call === Function.call`.

Comment: is this similar to the Java "Class" Class?

Comment: @valepu Kind of, yes. If JavaScript was a class-based language we would say `Function` is an instance of `Function`, but in Java `Class` is *not* an instance of `Class` (because classes aren't instances of `Class`, or of anything, in general). `Class` still does have a weird recursion thing going on though, because it has an associated class object, of type `Class`, and `Class.class == Class.class.getClass()`.

Comment: If this confuses you, just wait until you see Smalltalk.

Comment: Yes i said similar because of that reason, i am well aware that class is not an instance of Class, i was just trying to find a similar example. In this case it's more like Function's parent is Function, though not 100% sure as i have never delved much into prototypal inheritance

Comment: I mean it about Smalltalk, by the way. The class of `Class` is `Class class`. The class of `Class class` is `Metaclass`. The class of `Metaclass` is `Metaclass class`. The class of `Metaclass class` is `Metaclass`, so the instance-of relationship contains loops. Bonus: `Class class` is a subclass of `Class`, so `Class` isn't just an instance of itself, it's an instance of a subclass of itself!

Comment: Ok that is indeed confusing! I'm not even sure of what i just read

Comment: @immibis: Roughly the same thing happens in Maths when one tries to encode a theory inside the theory itself: objects with confusing relationships to each other.

Comment: [Wikipedia has a diagram that clarifies not much](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Smalltalk_metaclass.png) (about Smalltalk that is, not JavaScript)